# How to merge with GitHub branches with web application?

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I am not using the standard Git program to work with GitHub. I am using Eclipse (creating local repositories, pushing.... ) and the GitHub web application. This is what I see in my `master` branch for my repository:

[image]

This is what I see for my other branch, the `HEAD` branch:

[image]

I am trying to use the branches overview to merge the two branches into the `master` branch (main branch). This is what I see.

[image]

From this page, how can I merge the two branches? I tried this

> https://help.github.com/articles/merging-branches/

but this was for the program.

Comment: Are you sure it's *possible* to do through the web interface? That won't affect the branches on your computer.

Comment: Eclipse probably has a way to do it.

Comment: Side note: calling a branch `HEAD` is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @immibis you know any good resources for doing it with eclipse?